# Magento 1.7 Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.7

Not sure how to figure out this error, I've been googling for a week and I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator' in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Couponvalidator...', Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Gclone/Couponvalidator/controllers/Adminhtml/CouponvalidatorController.php(32): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('Couponvalidator...')
#3 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Gclone/Couponvalidator/controllers/Adminhtml/CouponvalidatorController.php(37): Gclone_Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_CouponvalidatorController->_initAction()
#4 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Gclone_Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_CouponvalidatorController->indexAction()
#5 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#6 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Thanks

That's the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gclone_Couponvalidator>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Gclone_Couponvalidator>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <couponvalidator>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Gclone_Couponvalidator</module>
                    <frontName>couponvalidator</frontName>
                </args>
            </couponvalidator>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <couponvalidator>
                    <file>couponvalidator.xml</file>
                </couponvalidator>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <couponvalidator>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Gclone_Couponvalidator</module>
                    <frontName>couponvalidator</frontName>
                </args>
            </couponvalidator>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
<!--        <menu>
            <couponvalidator module="couponvalidator">
                <title>Couponvalidator</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="couponvalidator">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </couponvalidator>
        </menu>-->

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <couponvalidator>
                    <file>couponvalidator.xml</file>
                </couponvalidator>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <couponvalidator>
                <class>Gclone_Couponvalidator_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>couponvalidator_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </couponvalidator>
            <couponvalidator_mysql4>
                <class>Gclone_Couponvalidator_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <couponvalidator>
                        <table>couponvalidator</table>
                    </couponvalidator>
                </entities>
            </couponvalidator_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <couponvalidator_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Gclone_Couponvalidator</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </couponvalidator_setup>
            <couponvalidator_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </couponvalidator_write>
            <couponvalidator_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </couponvalidator_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <couponvalidator>
                <class>Gclone_Couponvalidator_Block</class>
            </couponvalidator>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <couponvalidator>
                <class>Gclone_Couponvalidator_Helper</class>
            </couponvalidator>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

The CouponvalidatorController.php

```
class Gclone_Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_CouponvalidatorController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

protected function _initAction() {
         $this->_title($this->__('Reports'))
         ->_title($this->__('Deals'))
         ->_title($this->__('Deals Ordered'));
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('couponvalidator/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'))
             ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator'));
    return $this;
}   

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction() {
    $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('couponvalidator/couponvalidator')->load($id);

    if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register('couponvalidator_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('couponvalidator/items');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('couponvalidator')->__('Item does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction() {
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
            try {   
                /* Starting upload */   
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');

                // Any extention would work
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                // Set the file upload mode 
                // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
                //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                // We set media as the upload dir
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

            //this way the name is saved in DB
            $data['filename'] = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        }


        $model = Mage::getModel('couponvalidator/couponvalidator');     
        $model->setData($data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        try {
            if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                    ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }   

            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('couponvalidator')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('couponvalidator')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function deleteAction() {
    if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('couponvalidator/couponvalidator');

            $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function massDeleteAction() {
    $couponvalidatorIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('couponvalidator');
    if(!is_array($couponvalidatorIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select item(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($couponvalidatorIds as $couponvalidatorId) {
                $couponvalidator = Mage::getModel('couponvalidator/couponvalidator')->load($couponvalidatorId);
                $couponvalidator->delete();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                    'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($couponvalidatorIds)
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function massStatusAction()
{
    $couponvalidatorIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('couponvalidator');
    if(!is_array($couponvalidatorIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($couponvalidatorIds as $couponvalidatorId) {
                $couponvalidator = Mage::getSingleton('couponvalidator/couponvalidator')
                    ->load($couponvalidatorId)
                    ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                    ->setIsMassupdate(true)
                    ->save();
            }
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($couponvalidatorIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'couponvalidator.csv';
    $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator_grid')
        ->getCsv();

    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
}

public function exportXmlAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'couponvalidator.xml';
    $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator_grid')
        ->getXml();

    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
}

protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
    $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
    $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
    $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
    $response->setBody($content);
    $response->sendResponse();
    die;
}
}
```

Comment: can you put Gclone_Couponvalidator module config.xml.it may be issue here

Comment: @t2time, Are you still using Coupon Validator module or you have removed/disabled it?

Comment: Thanks for reply guys,@MTM yes i am still using it

Comment: can you put CouponvalidatorController.php  code

Comment: </menu>--> change to  </menu> --> it need space between  </menu> -->

Comment: ALSO  check Couponvalidator.php at  Gclone>Couponvalidator>Block>Adminhtml exit then it class should be Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator be  Gclone_Couponvalidator_Block_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator

Comment: hey check my explain nation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are issue in

```
->createBlock('Couponvalidator_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator')
```

should be

```
->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator')
```

in

```
createBlock you need call a block  in logic
```

**'blocktype/rest_of_file_path'**

couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator

couponvalidator is as block type which define in config.xml

```
 <blocks>
            <couponvalidator>
                <class>Gclone_Couponvalidator_Block</class>
            </couponvalidator>
        </blocks>
```

Here  `couponvalidator` is `a block typ`e  and `it class define in xml Gclone_Couponvalidator_Block`

and `adminhtml_couponvalidator` is call  rest of class `Adminhtml_Couponvalidator`.

if you run `->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator')` c`ode then magento is class`  `Gclone_Couponvalidator_Block_Adminhtml_Couponvalidator`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `_initAction()` function of controller file `CouponvalidatorController.php` as following and focus on the line `->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator'));`

```
protected function _initAction() {
     $this->_title($this->__('Reports'))
     ->_title($this->__('Deals'))
     ->_title($this->__('Deals Ordered'));
$this->loadLayout()
    ->_setActiveMenu('couponvalidator/items')
    ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'))
         ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('couponvalidator/adminhtml_couponvalidator'));
     return $this;
}
```